# Is the painting “Gallifrey Falls No More” actually Gallifrey?

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of the episode "Day of the Doctor”, the Doctor has a conversation with a character named “The Curator".  During this conversation the Curator, about the painting, states "I acquired it in remarkable circumstances."  The Curator then tells the Doctor the title is actually “Gallifrey Falls No More” and asks him "What do you suppose that means"? The Curator implies to the Doctor that he should search for Gallifrey and that the Curator is the Doctor in the future and that he has found Gallifrey but "Perhaps it doesn’t matter either way, who knows?".

The Curator explained that the painting's full title was “Gallifrey Falls No More”, and heavily implied that it in fact depicted the Fall of Arcadia at the moment the Doctors were successful in freezing Gallifrey and hiding it in a pocket universe. The painting is a stasis cube, a form of Time Lord art found on Gallifrey, which the Eleventh Doctor described as "a slice of real time" held in perfect stasis in a frame.

Is the painting “Gallifrey Falls No More” actually Gallifrey?

Comment: I have trouble buying the Curator as a future iteration of the Doctor, since the actor is Tom Baker (fourth Doctor). :P

Comment: @BrianS: [“DOCTOR: I never forget a face. CURATOR: I know you don't. And in years to come, you might find yourself revisiting a few. But just the old favourites, eh?”](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/34-1.htm)

Comment: You should change the title. Asking if the painting is OF Gallifrey is different than asking if it is Gallifrey itself.

Answer (score 9):

First, The Fall of Arcadia was not the end of the war. It was the impetus that finally pushed the War Doctor to steal the Moment and make the decision to end the war. This is where he leaves the "NO MORE" message on the wall, no doubt contributing to the name of the painting. So the two moments in time are not the same.

Second, what the Doctors did was *similar* to the stasis cube, but not the same. They shifted Gallifrey into a pocket dimension. It was a side effect that time-locked them, but as we saw from "Time of the Doctor", they weren't *frozen* in perfect stasis, as they could still send the message -- and the regeneration energy -- through the Crack.

So, no, I don't believe the painting is meant to be the actual Gallifrey.

Comment: They didn't do something similar to a stasis cube, they literally froze Gallifrey in a stasis cube and moved it into a pocket dimension.

Answer (score 4):

The painting at the beginning of the 50th Anniversary was said to be named Gallifrey Falls or No More.

http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Gallifrey_Falls_No_More

> Gallifrey Falls No More was a Gallifreyan landscape painting and
>   stasis cube, depicting Gallifrey in the final days of the Last Great
>   Time War. The painting specifically depicted the Fall of Arcadia on
>   the last day of the Time War. There were believed to be two
>   conflicting titles of the painting: No More, or Gallifrey Falls.

The Doctors were able to use the Statis Cube technology that was used to create the painting to save Gallifrey.

http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Stasis_cube

> A stasis cube was a form of Time Lord art found on Gallifrey, which
>   the Eleventh Doctor described as a "little sliver of time" held in
>   perfect stasis in a frame. The result, according to Clara Oswald,
>   resembled a 3D oil painting.

The Doctor had to use all his different incarnations' TARDIS'es to complete the goal of sealing Gallifrey in one.

> Later, having circumvented the time-lock and traveled back to the
>   events of the Last Great Time War, thirteen incarnations of the Doctor
>   came together to lock the planet Gallifrey in a stasis cube, thus
>   saving the planet while making it seem that the Time Lords and Daleks
>   finally obliterated each other.

http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Doctor_(TV_story)

> They have changed their minds about using the Moment, and the Eleventh
>   Doctor disarms the device with his sonic screwdriver. Instead, they
>   intend to freeze Gallifrey in a moment in time, slipped away in a
>   pocket universe, the way the Zygons froze themselves into Time Lord
>   art.

The Curator at the end stated that the true name of the painting wasn't either one of the previously contradictory titles but both of them put together, hinting that Gallifrey was indeed saved because "Gallifrey Falls No More".

Technically speaking though the painting is actually Gallifrey though because a stasis cube was a sliver of time held in perfect state.  It is essentially a moment in the Time War, at the Fall of Arcadia frozen in perfect stasis.  This is the whole reason why they were able to save Gallifrey because they basically took the entire planet and put it in a stasis cube and into another dimension.

Answer (score 0):

From *The End of Time, Part Two*:

> PARTISAN: Perhaps it's time. This is only the furthest edge of the Time War. But at its heart, millions die every second, lost in bloodlust and insanity. With time itself resurrecting them, to find new ways of dying over and over again. A travesty of life. Isn't it better to end it, at last?
>
> RASSILON: Thank you for your opinion.
> (The Lord President stands and aims his blue metal gauntlet at the Partisan. Energy strikes her, she screams and is atomised.)

Gallifrey IS trapped in a pocket dimension within a Time Lord stasis cube, reliving the same slice of time in an infinite loop; and yet the Time Lords are completely aware that it is happening.

The painting is merely the visual effect caused by the perspective of an observer outside the stasis cube.

It was only after the doctors "saved" Gallifrey that the time lords within the stasis cube found a way of sending the drumbeats across time which drove The Master mad; and only after their leader was defeated that they found the crack in the universe from the Tardis explosion which opened on Trenzalore in the town called Christmas.

Time travel stories are difficult to follow.

Comment: By that logic, shouldn't the painting have been destroyed by The Doctor's actions? I don't recall any mention of this.